# How can I create Views in xml which I can use for any layout?

Tags: android

When creating an `ImageView` for example, I know I can create it within a `Layout`:

Example a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout...>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@id/hello_world_id"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But can I define an `View` outside a layout, and then add it to any other layout?

I want to have a `RelativeLayout` which adds/removes views programmatically and dynamically, so that the `RelativeLayout` starts off with no views inside it, then I add some, remove some etc. Would there be any way to do this? Or is it better just to have these views already inside some other `Layout`, and then I add the `Layout` (whatever it is--containing my view(s)) to my `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Layout is the way to position views .you create your view and add or remove it according to your need .example `View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is `LayoutInflator`

1. Create a xml file - buttons.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout...>
   <ImageView
   android:id="@id/hello_world_id"/>
   ```
2. In your activity access it by

> ```
> final LayoutInflater  inflater 
>  = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>             View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons,
>                     null);// this is a layout in your master activity 
>
>     lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1); 
>     lLayout.addView(itemView);
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Currently, I'm doing this all programmatically. I have a `RelativeLayout` which I keep a reference to called `relative_layout`, and it doesn't have any children. I create `ImageView`s programmatically by calling `new ImageView(context)` and call `relative_layout.addView(imageview)` or `remove_view`. I post a runnable to the main thread, containing the code to add/remove the imageview It works 99% of the time, but sometimes, at random points, I can't add or remove any of my views. Could this be because of bad programming? I'm resorting to just using xml to simplify things.

Comment: difficult to predict. If you face issues. you can post some code, i will try to help :)